# General error: 1030 Got error 28 from storage engine - Large Empty disk space

Tags: mysql, hard-drive, diskspace

I am programming an online application and I bought a new server for it. The application is still in testing mode (very small amounts of traffic).

When the application is released, it is going to get hit pretty hard with traffic. I want to make sure my server is ready.

Today I hit this on an insert statement:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 28 from storage engine'
```

After doing a google search, I found at that the problem is *supposed* to be from running out of disk space. However, this is a new (dedicated) server with hardly anything on it. mysql itself is on a 120 GB SSD.

```
[root@host ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2              2.0G  476M  1.4G  26% /
/dev/md6              829G  648M  786G   1% /home
/dev/md5               39G  530M   37G   2% /var
/dev/md4               20G  4.1G   15G  23% /usr
/dev/md3              2.0G   36M  1.9G   2% /tmp
/dev/md0              190M   19M  162M  11% /boot
/dev/sdd1             109G  302M  103G   1% /var/lib/mysql
/dev/sdc1             903G  886M  855G   1% /backup
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

I'm not quite sure why it has so many drives. It was supposed to have 3x1TB SATA drives and 1X120GB SSD. Anyways, any insight on the problem would be very helpful!

Also, the error only happened *once*. So its not a huge deal, but I am worried it will happen more once the application is released.

Comment: Is your mysql process limited by a storage quota?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I am not sure though. How can I check?

Comment: Depends on your OS.  Try `repquota`?

Comment: these are not drives. they are mount points. fdisk -l will tell you about the drives you have. You can also use this utility to create more partitions if you wish and then more mount points for those partitions.. Depending on your SSD , they have garbage collectors they usually causes these issues.